# Как извлекать из второго массива элементы используя значения первого

Tags: java

Имеются 2 массива `List`, в первом у меня генерируются нужные мне индексы допустим 1 и 4, мне нужно доставать из второго массива элементы с этими индексами (то есть по счету) 1 и 4, как мне это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А чем не подходит `array2[array1[i]]`?

Comment: @nick_n_a не понял вас

Comment: @nick_n_a, но проблема уже решена

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте написать что-то в таком стиле.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    indexes.add(1);
    indexes.add(3);
    indexes.add(5);

    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(1);
    values.add(2);
    values.add(3);
    values.add(4);
    values.add(5);
    values.add(6);
    values.add(7);
    values.add(8);

    for (Integer index : indexes) {
        System.out.println(values.get(index));
    }
}
```

Ну если я верно понял вашу задачу

Comment: Под мою задачу пришлось переделать, но спасибо за идею, все получилось после не большой отладки